# Point to be noted

Tags: active-voice

Point to be noted. 
Hallo, teachers. 
I am muddled here. 
Either this is a passive sentence or not?
I am still looking for the reason behind this sentence. 
If this is a passive sentence, so where the "be"verb "is.

Can't I say , point is to be noted? 
How can we make its active sentence? 
Can I say,  someone is to note point? 
Point is to be noted. 
So , point to be noted. 
What are your remarks?
I asked my teacher about this sentence he told me that it is usually used in News papers. 
So please guide me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of an **elliptical construction** where some parts of the sentence are intentionally omitted. **Point to be noted** is as good as writing **This is a point to be noted**. The "This is" is omitted here. The meaning of the sentence says the event or matter is a point of importance and should be noted for future reference.

> Eg: The assistant lawyer remarks, "The client was not at home at that
>   hour."  The lawyer replies, "Yes. Point to be noted."

Answer (score 1):

This is, technically, not a sentence, so it does not need to have a "be" verb.

It is actually a noun phrase in passive voice with the to-infinitive behind as a midifier.

"Point to note" is the noun phrase in active voice.